# Sudo command in perl/eBox/Zentyal

Tags: linux, shell, perl, zentyal

I installed Zentyal 4.0 and looking its scripts how it is functioning.

I saw a perl function to run the shell commands in machine like below

```
//Ebox::Sudo:root
```

...

```
/usr/bin/sudo -p sudo: {commands to perform}
```

Can anyone explain what it is meant `sudo` in the shell?

Thanks

Comment: This is most certainly a duplicate question. I am looking for a dupe target and will hammer in a moment.

Comment: In the meantime, please run `man sudo` and read that manpage.

Comment: Relevant:  https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/80344/25912, https://serverfault.com/q/166374/156128

Comment: The best target I found is https://stackoverflow.com/q/43898333/1331451. The answer fits this question, but not the question it's written for, and it's not accepted.

Comment: @simbabque thanks for your reply Sir. I have not found an exact thought what I want to understand. That's why I post this question. I want to clear my doubt. This shell command was run at a perl script. right? how it is running without prompting the password from user.

Comment: As @Barnard mentioned we can add NoPasswd for certain paths and services. But here I have not made any changes in sudoers list to make special permissions as without password. Still Zentyal/EBox able to run shell commands. It will be good to know the depth. :)        This is the script from github: https://github.com/zentyal/zentyal/blob/4.0/main/common/src/EBox/Sudo.pm   Line no: 183. All is well :)

Answer (score 1):

The -p according to documentation is for (Use a custom password prompt with optional escape sequences)
zentyal used the  /usr/bin/sudo -p sudo: just for purpose of testing

```
Readonly::Scalar our $SUDO_PATH   => '/usr/bin/sudo -p sudo:'; # our declaration eases testing
```

Because if you change to

```
/usr/bin/sudo -p anything:
```

The functionality of sudo zentyal is normal.

In you comments you wanted know why zentyal can run any shell system command without prompting the password, is because when you installed zentyal you have to set a user to sudo group or admin (this is similar to sudo group)

Members of the admin group may gain root privileges
%admin ALL=(ALL) ALL

The last ALL allowed **to run any command**

Case related:
https://forum.zentyal.org/index.php/topic,34663.0.html

Answer (score 0):

This answer gives you an answer to both the `sudo` and `-p sudo:` in your command.

`sudo` itself is a privilege command allowing users to execute commands, if allowed in the `sudoers` file, which generally is not allowed by normal users.

The sudoers file can determine exactly which commands a user is allowed to run.
Typically these commands can be run by either setting up the sudoers file by either prompting for the user password each time a command is being run, or by adding the NOPASSWD option which allows a user to run sudo commands without having to retype their password.

Example:
a normal user cannot run dmidecode as you will get a access denied.

```
[user@host ~]$ dmidecode
# dmidecode 3.0
Scanning /dev/mem for entry point.
/dev/mem: Permission denied
```

but if allowed in the sudoers file, you can allow the user to run the command as a super user.

```
[user@host ~]$ sudo dmidecode
```

Here is an example of a sudoers file entry allowing user to only run some `dmidecode` and `sar` using sudo, without prompting for password.

```
user123 ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/sbin/dmidecode, /usr/bin/sar
```

for the `-p sudo:` part.

The `-p` (prompt) option allows you to override the default password prompt and use a custom one.  The following percent (‘%’) escapes are supported by the sudoers.

In other words in this case it will replace the default prompt for sudo password with the `sudo:` text.

So as an example, running a command like `df -h`

```
[user@phost ~]$ sudo df -h
[sudo] password for host:
```

but when running with `-p`

```
[user@phost ~]$ sudo -p sudo: df -h
sudo:
```

**TIP!** whenever you need to edit a sudoers file, you need to ensure you never do `vi sudoers` as it will change file ownership. Always edit a sudoers file by running the `visudo` command as `root`.